# Xlib error "extension "GLX" missing on display" on VirtualBox guest OS

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, opengl, jenkins

I have a remote build-machine with Jenkins and I'm trying to run GUI application. In Jenkins I installed Xvnc plugin, which uses TightVNC Server, but each build has failed.
Earlier, there was a problem with loading driver swrast (by libGL), currently  in the log there are this lines:

```
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":51".
(...)
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":51".
Terminating xvnc.
$ vncserver -kill :51
Killing Xtightvnc process ID 22513
```

When I changed system to use Xvnc4server instead of tightvncserver, the output is:

```
[Warning] QXcbConnection: Failed to initialize XRandr
[Warning] Qt: XKEYBOARD extension not present on the X server. 
(...)
[Warning] Unrecognized OpenGL version
[Warning] Unrecognized OpenGL version
Terminating xvnc.
$ vncserver -kill :47
Killing Xvnc4 process ID 26522
```

Remote desktop is Ubuntu 14.04 running over VirtualBox, so I installed VBoxAddons but it didn't resolve the problem. Below I'm putting some logs, maybe helpful for you.

```
$ cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep GL -is
[266219.686] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[266219.686] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[266219.687] (II) Module glx: vendor="Advanced Micro Devices, Inc."
[266219.687] Loading extension GLX
[266219.687] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout


$ lsmod | grep box
vboxsf                 43786  0 
vboxpci                23194  0 
vboxnetadp             25670  0 
vboxnetflt             27613  0 
vboxdrv               339502  3 vboxnetadp,vboxnetflt,vboxpci
vboxvideo              12658  0 
vboxguest             248441  8 vboxsf
drm                   302817  1 vboxvideo

$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: InnoTek Systemberatung GmbH VirtualBox Graphics Adapter

$ glxinfo 
Error: unable to open display
```

Any ideas what should I do?

Comment: You might want this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualGL

Comment: But to use VirtualGL on VirtualBox Guest I need to install its at host OS, right? What if I haven't access to host machine?